# R - removing data table rows based on two values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame (tbl_df) with approximately the following information:

```
data <- data.frame(Energy = sample(1:200, 100, replace = T), strip1 = sample(1:12, 100, replace = T), strip2 = sample(1:12, 100, replace = T))
```

It has 3 columns. The first is energy, the second and third are strip numbers (where energy was deposited).

Each strip has a different threshold and these are stored in two numeric arrays, each position in the array is for the corresponding strip number:

```
threshold_strip1 <- c(4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 2, 2)
threshold_strip2 <- c(5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 7, 7, 10, 2, 2, 2)
```

These tell me the minimum amount of energy the strip can receive. What I want to be able to do is remove the rows from the data frame where BOTH strips do not have over the required threshold.

As an example, if I have the row:

```
Energy = 4, strip1 = 2, strip2 = 2
```

Then I would remove this row as although strip2 has a lower threshold than 4, strip1 has a threshold of 6 and so there isn't enough energy here.

Apologies if this question is worded poorly, I couldn't seem to find anything like it in old questions.

Comment: In your example, why are you comparing strip2 = 2 with 4, and why is strip1 = 2 being compared with 6?

Comment: Hi, this was poorly worded on my end. The strip number relates to the position in the threshold arrays. Position 2 for each is 6 and 3 respectively. If the energy i am looking at is 4 in the example then both thresholds must be lower than this. As 6 > 4 I want to remove that event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filter1 <- data$strip1 >= threshold_strip1[data$strip1]
filter2 <- data$strip2 >= threshold_strip1[data$strip2]

data <- subset(data, filter1 & filter2)
```

Comment: I ended up using this answer, but it should be edited to be: data$Energy >= threshold_strip1[data$strip1] Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd maybe do...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

# structure lower-bound rules
threshes = list(threshold_strip1, threshold_strip2)
lbDT = data.table(
  strip_loc = rep(seq_along(threshes), lengths(threshes)),
  strip_num = unlist(lapply(threshes, seq_along)),
  thresh    = unlist(threshes)
)

# loop over strip locations (strip1, strip2, etc)
# marking where threshold is not met
data[, keep := TRUE]
lbDT[, {
  onexpr = c(sprintf("strip%s==s", strip_loc), "Energy<th")
  data[.(s = strip_num, th = thresh), on=onexpr, keep := FALSE]
  NULL
}, by=strip_loc]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Using `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)

data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(
    strip1_value = threshold_strip1[strip1],
    strip2_value = threshold_strip2[strip2],
    to_keep = Energy > strip1_value & Energy > strip2_value
  ) %>%
  filter(to_keep == TRUE)
```